# Platform-wide suspenson but not on MO?

Tags: bug, specific-user, account-suspension

At [this closed question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/373476/) the [user](https://mathoverflow.net/users/166587/aba-saba) seems to be playing ignorant, but I looked at their [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/19608331/aba-saba?tab=accounts) and some of the other StackExchange sites, and there is a prominent banner

> This account is temporarily suspended network-wide. The suspension period ends on Oct 5 '21 at 21:22.

on all the ones I checked. How was this user able to ask a question on MathOverflow?

Comment: I know nothing about this specific user’s situation, but for one thing, a user with a network-wide suspension may be manually unsuspended on any particular site by a moderator, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257498/user-is-suspended-network-wide-except-not-really .

Comment: Actually, are you sure this was really this user’s network profile in the technical sense? The (now apparently deleted) MO user profile could have been a new user account unattached to the suspended network account (even if presumably created by the same person).

Comment: Well, I only got to the network profile from clicking through from here, so I don't really know. I suspect this user has been here before, asking questions relating RH to the zeta function as a wave, and other really peculiar questions about vaguely race-related issues on other SE sites.

Comment: Re: @DavidRoberts last comment- see the other Meta question https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4664/one-person-creating-multiple-riemann-hypothesis-related-accounts

Comment: @DavidRoberts Don't forget the claim that apparently all answers on MO are just people copying results of Google searches

Comment: @YemonChoi I missed that one!

Comment: @DavidRoberts All right, this should work, thank you. I couldn't test it myself as the MO profile had already been deleted, and I didn't know if you used this or another method (such as searching for the user name).